# How to return values from function - React native

Tags: function, react-native, return-value

How to return a boolean value from react native function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it can be accomplish like this:

```
export function isJson(str) {
  try {
    JSON.parse(str);
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

This function checks whether provided value is valid `JSON` or not.

Answer (score 3):

If your function is in a class, you can do this (check toggleBool):

```
class IsTrue extends Component
{
    state = {isTrue: false}

    componentWillMount = () =>
    {
        const   newVal = this.toggleBool();

        this.setState({isTrue: newVal});
    }

    toggleBool = () =>
    {
        if (this.state.isTrue === false)
            return (true);
        return (false);
    }


    render = () => <Text>{this.state.isTrue}</Text>
}
```